# make document viewer keep page

Tags: pdf, 22.04, document

after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 from the 20.04 I have this problem with the default GNOME document viewer

I'm reading some books in pdf and in the 20.04 after closing the file , when I opened it again, it would start on the page where it was left

Right now every time the document viewer just opens the first page...

It's pretty annoying, is there any way to fx this?